# What is tsconfig$paths in PhpStorm and how to get rid of it?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

In PhpStorm, in one of my projects, I got this thing under External libraries.

When I go to a TypeScript file and hit "Find it in the file tree", it's highlighted twice: once in the project folder, the second time in the `tsconfig$paths`.

And it's annoying since by default it moves me to External libraries. I couldn't find how to remove the folder or whatever it is?

[image]

**update**

My tsconfigs are:

1. tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@root/*": ["../"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "nightwatch.conf.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

3. tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does your tsconfig.json look like?

Comment: There are few of them, going to update the question now